# Matlab: Documentation on handle variables and mat files?

Tags: matlab, oop, handle

Is there any TMW documentation on how handle variables are treated when saving and loading mat files?  From trial and error, I've determined rudimentary behaviour, e.g., that the underlying object is stored to the mat file, and loaded from the mat file, but the actual class definition itself is not.  That is, of you load a handle object, but your class definition has been modified by adding fields, the loaded object will have these additional fields, though they won't be initialized with values.

A more comprehensive documentation of the designed-for behaviour is indispensible for those defining handle classes in object oriented programming.  For example, what if you save object A to a mat file, and it has a property that refers to an object Z, then you save object B to a mat file, and it also contains a property referring to object Z?  If I load each of the two mat files, will I have two separate instances of object Z, or will the two variables reference the same object?

Another scenario may be two handle object variables referring to the same object, but one variable is in the base workspace and the other variable is actually a property of another object?  If I save and load, would the two variables still point to the same object?

I know that I can empirically reverse engineer each possible scenario, but it's much less efficient than reading a behavioural specification (if one exists).

Comment: Have you looked at [Save and Load Process for Objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/understanding-the-save-and-load-process.html)?  It describes the use of saveobj and loadobj methods to correctly handle save and load, and what happens when the object definition has changed.

Comment: I appreciate the link, Phil, but I fear that I may have obfuscated the question by providing an example of what I reverse-engineered.  I'm actually looking for how handle class object variables are treated. I don't think of them as "normal" object variables because they are more like reference variables (in the C++ vernacular, if I correctly recall my C++ from 10+ years ago).  I'll revise the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank the respondents. Their answers have been very helpful.  However, the question was whether the save/load behaviour of handle object variables was documented. The answer seems to be "no", and I will ask TMW if they feel it is worthwhile documenting this.

Further to Jonas's info on save/load behaviour, I created the following test to determine the difference in load behaviour when (i) the whole workspace is loaded versus (ii) individual handle object variables.  As I surmised in the comments, multiple handles to the same object maintain their reference to a common object in case (i), but they refer to separate (but identical) objects in case (ii):

```
% myClassA.m
%-----------
% Handle class
classdef myClassA < handle
properties
   myPropA
end % properties
end % classdef

% myClassB.m
%-----------
% The property will refer to a
% handle class object
classdef myClassB
properties
   myObjA
end % properties
end % classdef

% test.m
%--------
% Main test script, uses the two
% classes
clc
echo on

% Create 2 object variables. 2nd
% one has a property that refers to
% same object as the first one
objA = myClassA
objA.myPropA = 5
objB = myClassB
objB.myObjA = objA

% Check that changes in handle object
% is seen from both variables
objA.myPropA = 7
objB.myObjA.myPropA % Should be 7

% Save & load entire workspace.
% Check that both variables refer
% to same object.
save('myWrkSpc')
clear classes
load('myWrkSpc')
objA
objB.myObjA
objA.myPropA = 9
objB.myObjA % Should be 9

% Load variables individually. Show
% that they now refer to separate
% objects
clear classes
load('myWrkSpc','objA')
load('myWrkSpc','objB')
objA
objB.myObjA
objA.myPropA = 9
objB.myObjA
   % Should still be 7 instead of 9

echo off
```

These are the scenarios that I have come across thus far, though I'm sure I'll run into new ones in which a thorough documentation of the designed-for behaviour would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Matlab handle objects are passed by reference as long as they are in memory. However, when they're saved and re-loaded, they are a new object, and thus, any references to and from them are "broken" (see example below). This is true for all objects of class handle, regardless of how complicated a case you construct (eg `objectA` being a property of `objectB` which is in turn a property of `objectA` will suddenly take up a lot more memory after being reloaded): Loading an object from disk creates a new, un-referenced instance.

```
objA = myHandleObject();
objB = objA; %# same object, changing A changes B
save('objOnDisk.mat','objB');
load('objOnDisk.mat') %# overwrites objB in the workspace
%# objB is no longer a reference of objA
```

This is particularly noticeable if you modify a handle object in e.g. a `parfor` loop on a cluster, as the workspace gets saved and reloaded on the individual workers.

There is one way around it: You can define the `loadobj` function to look for other objects of the same class, and if you add a unique reference number to each (set a property to `tempname`, for example), you can "rebuild" the references manually. Been there, done that, but cannot recommend because it gets really complex real fast.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I think it's a good answer for a specific situation. I was really hoping, however, that there was documentation on major scenarios involving saving/loading handle objects. E.g., what if I have 2 variables referencing the same object? Just to complicate things, what if one was in the base workspace and the other was a property of another object? What if I loaded each of those two objects using separate statements? I can test each scenario, but I'm hoping that this is not necessary, i.e., that the overall behaviour of save/load with regards to handle objects is documented.

Comment: I said that the question has to do with general documentation rather than a specific scenario.  So I up-voted instead of accepting the answer.  However, I was puzzled by the absence of an acceptance checkmark icon.  According to the [meta page on accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), the only timing constraint is that one must wait 15 minutes after the question is posted.

Comment: @user36800: I've added a couple of sentences to clarify that this is really a universal behavior, and not limited to the example I provided. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas.  I'm going to follow up (once I have access to the machine with Matlab) to check the final scenario: One variable in base workspace, another that is a property of an object in a base workspace, both referencing the same object. I'll save the whole workspace, and for test 1, load the entire workspace to confirm that they both reference the same object. Test 2 would be to load just the reference variable, then load the object whose property refers to the same object. For Test 2, I expect the result that you demonstrate in your answer. For test 1...we'll see.

Comment: But I take it a the answer to the original question is that there is no documentation on these little details (of which I'm sure there are scenarios that I haven't anticipated)?  If so, I'm going to see if TMW is willing to include such behavioural descriptions in their documentation. Otherwise people are left reverse engineering the behaviour.